# Write custom plugin for a task of type Zip

Tags: gradle

When I write a task of type `Copy` in custom plugin, I do this:

```
class CopyJarsTask extends DefaultTask {
   @TaskAction
   def copyJars(){
      project.copy {
         from('libs')
         include("**/*")
         into "jars"
      }
   }
}
```

Similarly, I want to write a task of type `Zip` but we don't have anything like project.zip in this case. How can I write a task of type `Zip` in custom plugin task class?

Comment: Are you sure it works? Could you please provide an example?

Comment: If you mean project.copy by it then I am sure that works

Comment: Yes, if it's located in annotated method. If you annotate just `project.copy` itself it fails.

Comment: I edited my code accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to extend the [`Zip`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/bundling/Zip.html) class and configure task's behavior in the constructor e.g.:

```
class CopyJarsTask extends Zip {

   CopyJarsTask() {
      from 'libs'
      baseName = 'libs'
   }
}

task archive(type: CopyJarsTask)
```

Comment: @TaskAction isnt required?How will I run this task

Comment: @sver, it's not. A task may contain no actions however in this particular case it will be inherited from `Zip` task. You just need to configure the task. You know execution vs configuration in gradle?

Comment: I have a question. where exactly I should write  task archive(type: CopyJarTask) . Is it in the same class ? Also, I am giving archiveName, from, include, exlude , destinationDir inside the constructor. Is that fine?